# How I can call this function in another class?

Tags: java, android

this is the MainActivity.Java. This function I want to call in another class

// Method to connect to FTP server:

```
public static boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
        String password, int port) {
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            mFTPClient
                    .setFileTransferMode(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: First of all I would recommend you to start from Core Java documentation.

Comment: actually i havn't FTP account.. so can anyone tell me how i can create an account on FTP.. because i have no idea and i am new user of android.

Answer (score 1):

The general way to call these sorts of functions is to use the class name before the method.

Let's say that this method exists in a class called FTPHelper. To call this piece of code, you would use

`FTPHelper.ftpConnect(host, username,password,port);`

Comment: but what I right in the parameters? Because of this I am confusing actually

Comment: So your saying you dont know what to put into the function? In order for us to help us with that, we need to know a bit more about what you are trying to connect to.